# Copy one table to another in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

How do i use the following insert into query in laravel 5?

```
INSERT INTO connection2.table (SELECT * from connection1.table);
```

I am looking for two different connections, Connection1.table record should goes to Connection2.table.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not directly use sql to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
$c1 = DB("Connection1")->select("SELECT * from table")

foreach($c1 as $record){

    DB("Connection2")->table("table")->insert(get_object_vars($record))

}
```

Comment: Great answer!  I'd also like to note that for large tables you may need to modify this a bit to chunk the results.  Otherwise you might run out of memory.

Comment: This is nice for small data and/or old laravel, for a bigger data and/or better performance, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218878/1835470 my answer below :)

Answer (score 3):

Since laravel 5.7+ `insertUsing(array $columns, Closure|Builder|string $query)` is available,

DOCS: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertUsing

therefore you can now make this whole query in Laravel chaining style like

```
DB::table('newTable')->insertUsing(
    ['column1', 'column2', 'column3',], // ..., columnN
    function ($query) {
        $query
            ->select(['column1', 'column2', 'column3',]) // ..., columnN
            ->from('oldTable');
            // optional: you could even add some conditions:
            // ->where('some_column', '=', 'somevalue')
            // ->whereNotNull('someColumn')
    }
);
```

`DB` here is set-up in `app.php` `'aliases'` as

`'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,`

Answer (score 0):

@Wistar,  Thanks for reply, with your code $record comes with an object class which is not accepted by insert, 
it required the array type.

I have used it as follows:

```
   DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $table_records = DB::connection('Connection1')->select("SELECT * from table");     
   DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); 

   DB::connection('Connection2')->table("table")->insert($table_records);
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe you could also use `get_object_vars`.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on how to chunk results in case of large tables.  You can of course chunk as you see fit, 5000 is just an example.

```
$chunk1 = DB("Connection1")->table("table")->orderBy("id")->chunk(5000, function($c1) {

    foreach($c1 as $record) {

        DB("Connection2")->table("table")->insert(get_object_vars($record))

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$basket_data = DB::table('baskets')->get();
foreach($basket_data as $records)
{
    DB::table('basket_after_payments')->insert(get_object_vars($records));
}
```

Comment: Here I am getting data from baskets table , and then all data that stored in $basket_data is inserting into table 'basket_after_payments'.